# $_POST variable contains no data

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm having a basic form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php" class="form">
    <input id="a" type="text" placeholder="Cod acces" name="access-code" size="20" required /><br>
    <input id="b" type="password" placeholder="Parola" name="password" autocomplete="new-password" size="20" required /><br>
    <input id="c" type="password" placeholder="Confirma parola" name="re-password" autocomplete="new-password" size="20" required /> <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" />
</form>
```

In register.php i have the following 3 lines of code:

```
$password = $_POST["password"];
$repassword = $_POST["re-password"];
$acces_code = $_POST["access-code"];
```

Even  if this code is as simple as it looks, my `$_POST` variable is empty. Even weirder, if I press F12 to see the request data, all variables and it's values are there.
I'm using XAMPP on Windows.

Comment: if you `echo $password;` it's empty?  After submitting the form of course.

Comment: Is `register.php` also the script that displays the form? The POST variables aren't set when the form is first displayed, only after the user submits the form.

Comment: @clearshot66, if i print $_POST (using print_r($_POST)) i just get "Array()", and just after that i get 3 errors  Undefined index: password(re-password, acces-code) in E:\path\to\project.

Comment: @Barmar, no, register.php is not the script that displays the form

Comment: Is this the only script that's having trouble getting POST variables?

Comment: Check the `variables_order` setting in `php.ini`, make sure it has `P` in it.

Comment: @Barmar No, even weirder, it happened on a project that was definitely working in the past days.

Comment: can you upload screenshot .. with output of ....   print_r($_POST)

Comment: Any server upgrades recently? https://serverfault.com/questions/127674/mysteriously-empty-post-array

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code I'm also with Windows version 10 and Xampp Server.

**In your `index.php` paste this code below**

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="register.php" class="form">
    <input id="a" type="text" placeholder="Cod acces" name="access-code" size="20" required /><br>
    <input id="b" type="password" placeholder="Parola" name="password" autocomplete="new-password" size="20" required /><br>
    <input id="c" type="password" placeholder="Confirma parola" name="re-password" autocomplete="new-password" size="20" required /> <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**and then in your `register.php` paste this code below**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register'])){

echo $password = $_POST["password"]." ";
echo $repassword = $_POST["re-password"]." ";
echo $acces_code = $_POST["access-code"]." ";

}
```

Successfully getting and outputting your input on the form. Hope this will help you